# An array from a NodeList while scraping with Puppeteer doesn't appear

Tags: arrays, asynchronous, web-scraping, puppeteer, nodelist

I'm trying to scape a website but I cannot find a way to show the results in the console.log. 
The script I've created is the following:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
    try { 
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(`https://www.coches.net/nuevo/km-0/`);
        await page.waitFor(4000);

        const news = await page.evaluate(() => {
            const urlsArray = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.mt-CardAd-link')).map(a => a.href);
            return urlsArray;
        });
        console.log(news);
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Browser Closed");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        await browser.close();
        console.log("Browser Closed");
    }
})();
```

While the variable **urlsArray** works in the devconsole of Chrome, it doesn't when launching the script in the terminal with the previous script. I tried everything but I don't find anything to solve this issue. 
**What I can do to finally be able to show this array with the console.log?**

Thank you!

Comment: For me this URL shows 403 now, so it doesn't have an anchor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script seems to be fine, but the page you´re trying to enter is examinating the cookies and blocking your script's access.

I believe you should take a look at this:
[How to avoid being detected as bot on Puppeteer and Phantomjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs)