# How to make that a page not detect that I am using the automatize control in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, java, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium

I'm working on a bot that buys by himself, but the page knows I'm using a bot maybe because the message  "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software", so I want to know if there is a way in pupeteer to launch a "regular version" of a browser simulating that is a human person so in that way not being tracked as a bot by the page.

I tried with

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
        executablePath: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe'
  });
```

but is the same using Chrome and chronium

Comment: Do you understand that the vendors don't want you to do this, because bots are not good for business?  It's constant battle.  Whatever you come up with today, they'll block tomorrow.

Comment: It will be hard to do, first make sure if the site's _Terms of Use_ allows you to do that (most probably it doesn't, that's why they block your browser instance). In general, you could do research on [puppeteer-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth) plugins, like 'stealth'. You will also find already answered questions on this topic, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs