# New tab doesnt open in puppeteer Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I am using Puppeteer to build an automated shopping bot. I have made this function `addToCart` to add a product to the cart. After adding the product, I want to open a new url in the same browser session but it's not working.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const product_url =
  "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08ZL7LZW3?pf_rd_r=J6QNRZDRJ7Z8FSF2HVXR&pf_rd_p=6fc81c8c-2a38-41c6-a68a-f78c79e7253f&pd_rd_r=d3adff00-5e6f-4456-8fd0-bd187f2ff86d&pd_rd_w=oO6kF&pd_rd_wg=aoGGq&ref_=pd_gw_unk";

const checkout_url = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/shipoptionselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1";

async function givePage() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  return page;
}

async function addToCart(page) {
  await page.goto(product_url);
  await page.waitForSelector(
    "button[class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt']"
  );

  await page.click(
    "button[class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt']",
    (elem) => elem.click()
  );
}

async function checkout() {
  var page = await givePage();
  await addToCart(page);
  await page.waitForNavigation();
  const page2 = await browser.newPage(); // open new tab
  await page2.goto("https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/shipoptionselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1"); // go to github.com
  await page2.bringToFront(); // make the tab active
}

checkout();
```

Comment: Your `browser` variable is declared *inside* `givePage()`, so you cannot use it in the `checkout()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `givePage` creates a new browser from scratch, but abandons the reference to the browser object when the function returns, making it impossible to get new pages or close it from a global context (it's possible to use `page.browser()` to close the browser locally, but it can't be shared between requests).

You may want to make one browser, pull one page from it, and repeatedly access that same page from different functions.

Alternately, you may wish to use one browser, then generate new pages ("tabs") on demand, as appears to be the case here.

Caching promises in variables is one way to achieve these things. In an outer scope, you can write

```
const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
```

Note that there's no `await`. The idea is to cache the promise that resolves to the browser. When `await browserPromise` is invoked later in the code, the promise always resolves to the same underlying browser instance. The same approach can work for pages -- `const pagePromise = browser.newPage();` invoked multiple times will always give you the same page object.

Another issue is that `page.click()` doesn't take a callback. If you want an untrusted click, use

```js
await page.$eval(
  "button[class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt']",
  (elem) => elem.click()
);
```

Also, if `page.click()` triggers a navigation, then `page.waitForNavigation()` needs to be set before or alongside the click to ensure navigation doesn't resolve before `page.waitForNavigation()` begins waiting. If it does, the navigation wait will time out. The typical pattern to avoid this race condition is:

```js
const navP = page.waitForNavigation();
await page.click("button[class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt']"); // triggers nav
await navP;
```

but on the current page, I don't think a nav is triggered when clicking this button (this may change in the future).

Finally, `[class=...]` CSS selector syntax is generally too rigid. It will fail if another class is added or the classes are reordered. Prefer `.foo.bar.baz` which is agnostic of order and works even if `.quux` is added to the class list. Better yet, use an id if available.

Here's an example. Error handling and [getting past Amazon's robot blocker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs) are left as exercises.

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer"); // ^21.2.1

const productUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B08ZL7LZW3?pf_rd_r=J6QNRZDRJ7Z8FSF2HVXR&pf_rd_p=6fc81c8c-2a38-41c6-a68a-f78c79e7253f&pd_rd_r=d3adff00-5e6f-4456-8fd0-bd187f2ff86d&pd_rd_w=oO6kF&pd_rd_wg=aoGGq&ref_=pd_gw_unk";
const checkoutUrl = "https://www.amazon.com/gp/buy/shipoptionselect/handlers/display.html?hasWorkingJavascript=1";

const browserPromise = puppeteer.launch({headless: false});

const newPage = () => browserPromise.then(browser => browser.newPage());

async function addToCart(page) {
  await page.goto(productUrl);
  const el = await page.waitForSelector("#add-to-cart-button");
  return el.evaluate(el => el.click());
}

async function checkout() {
  const page = await newPage();
  await addToCart(page);
  const page2 = await newPage();
  await page2.goto(checkoutUrl);
  await page2.bringToFront();
  const browser = await browserPromise;
  await browser.close();
}

checkout();
```

That said, for small scripts like this you can always inline all of the code in one function. If your script performs a simple task and can be written in 10 or 20 lines to code, it's probably premature to create abstractions like this.

For larger scripts, you may want to increase abstraction and gather the browser and relevant page functions in a class or object, but whether you have an object property or a loose promise, the underlying approach of `awaiting` one browser or page promise repeatedly is the same.

Comment: HI, @ggorlen Thanks for the detailed explanation. I tried this solution but got the unhandled promise rejection warning and the new tab didn't open with the required URL.

Comment: What was the error message, specifically? As I mentioned in the post, Amazon will probably detect that you're a robot and block the request, causing a timeout (```TimeoutError: waiting for selector `button[class='single_add_to_cart_button button alt']` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded```).  That's a different problem than making the browser object accessible by caching the promise. If you comment out `await addToCart(page);` and `await page.waitForNavigation();` you'll see that the fundamental pattern is sound, then follow the tips in the linked post to bypass the robot detector.