# some sites don't connect using wget or curl commands on my server

Tags: javascript, server, request, puppeteer, wget

I'm trying to make a request to a website through the puppeteer on my server but it doesn't work, but I realized that using wget doesn't work either, when I make this request on my personal computer it works normally, I think the website has something that identifies that it's a server and it doesn't return anything, because I tested it on several servers and it didn't work, then I tested it on several different pc from colleagues and it worked normally

website: https://www.tse.jus.br/

code: `wget -S "https://www.tse.jus.br/"` it just doesn't work on the servers.

code in puppeteer: `await page.goto("https://www.tse.jus.br/")` same thing

is there a way it might work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid being detected as bot on Puppeteer and Phantomjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs)

Comment: @theDavidBarton unfortunately no, I've tried this before.