# Puppeteer not loading complete page render

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scrape from an MT5 server. On my browser the site shows loading for a few seconds or milliseconds then renders the login form. But with puppeter it doesn't. Just the loading page like forever, till timeout. And when i try to code puppeteer wait until the element is rendered it crashes after timeout. I have tried different methods to find out whats wrong(Some of which i commented out in my code). I don't know where i got it wrong or is it from the site?

This is my first time using Puppeteer too.
My Code is below. Any body that can help me out with solutions?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const baseUrl = "https://trade.mql5.com/trade?servers=";

const getData = async () => {
  console.log(baseUrl);
  // launch pupprteer
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  //   await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(60000);
  await page.goto(baseUrl, { waitUntil: "networkidle2", timeout: 0 });
  //   await page.waitForNavigation(() =>
  //     document.querySelector("#hero-head-circle")
  //   );
  //   await page.screenshot({ path: "login.png" });
  await page.waitForSelector("#login"),
    await page.screenshot({ path: "login.png" });

  await browser.close();
};

getData();
```

Comment: Did you try adding a user agent, puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth or any other [strategies for avoiding detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs)?

Comment: no i didn't. Don't know what that is. This is my first time. I'll look it up

Answer (score 1):

I think i had the same issue, somepages load content as you scroll down through them, so the selector #login may not be apppering unless you scroll down; if that is the issue try with this code:

```
const { scrollPageToBottom } = require('puppeteer-autoscroll-down')       
const lastPosition= await scrollPageToBottom(page, {
            size: 110,
            delay: 250,
        })
```

This solved the issue for me. Have in mind that you may have to change "size" and "delay" depending on the page that you are using.

Comment: Using scrollPageToBottom with page.setViewport saved my day. tnx!