# Can a browser detect if it is being operated or launched by Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am currently learning to scrape websites using the Puppeteer library on Node.js. I've observed that certain websites don't allow login when the browser is launched using Puppeteer. For example, when I attempt to scrape Google.com, Google detects unusual browser behavior and requests my confirmation via a checkbox to verify that I'm not a robot.

My question is, how can a browser detect whether my activity is being operated by Puppeteer or not? Is there a way to prevent detection and mimic human-like behavior when using Puppeteer?

Below is a snippet of my simple code for reference.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const testRun = async () => {
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
    }
    
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 0,
    });
};

testRun();
```

Comment: Yes, browsers can detect robots. Puppeteer's default [user agent](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.browser.useragent) is `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36` which says it's headless Chrome right there. [Changing it to something else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70936552/6243352) is the first step, but there are probably hundreds of additional steps you can do. See https://bot.sannysoft.com/. There's no silver bullet for bypassing blocks, though, so please share the site you're trying to manipulate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid being detected as bot on Puppeteer and Phantomjs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731848/how-to-avoid-being-detected-as-bot-on-puppeteer-and-phantomjs)